# Composite Primary key too long?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, primary-key

I am using mysql 5.5 on Ubuntu 13.04 to store similarity measures [-1,1] between URIs.
My table layout is very simple:

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
| uri1               | uri2                | value |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|http://foo.com/bar  | http://bar.net/foo  | 0.8   |
|http://foo.com/bar1 | http://bar.net/foo2 | 0.4   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to make sure that for two specific uris, not more than one value is stored. Therefore, I use the followin sql to create the table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table(
  uri1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  uri2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  value DOUBLE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (uri1, uri2),
  INDEX (value) )
```

Unfortunately, when I am batch-inserting data (via Java JDBC), I get Exceptions like the following:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry
 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Document-http://purl.org/linked-data/c' 
for key 'PRIMARY'
```

It seems like the primary key is not long enough to store both URIs and I therefore get duplicate entry exceptions when the prefix is the same (which it is often in my data).
I have checked and no "real" duplicates are inserted.
Is there a way to set the length of the primary key so that it will always contain both URIs completely? Or is there generally a better way to model the data?

I do not want to perform a check if a row with the supplied uri1 and uri2 already exists whenever I insert data, but rather handle the exception if this may actually happen (which it shouldn't). Therefore, I think, it is not feasible to just use an incrementing integer as primary key.

In my application, I will be creating several tables like this for different measures and may later want to join them by uri1 and uri2, so that I get a result that contains from different tables all the values for a specific pair of uris.

I have found out something else:
I set up the connection in Java like this:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true",
 "user","pass");
```

When I do not use "rewriteBatchedStatements=true", it seems to work fine. Unfortunately, I really have to use this, since the batch inserts are orders of magnitude slower if I don't.

Here is the additionally requested code:

```
//Initialized in Constructor
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true",
                "user","pass");

PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(String.format("INSERT INTO %s.%s values (?, ?, ?)", dbName, tableName));
//

public void queue(ResDescriptor row, ResDescriptor column, double simil) {
    if(!operational()) return;
    try {
        String uri1 = row.getType();
        String uri2 = column.getType();
        pst.setString(1, uri1);
        pst.setString(2, uri2);
        pst.setDouble(3, simil);            
        pst.addBatch();

        if(++batchCount%maxBatch == 0){
            pst.executeBatch();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

getType() always returns a URI-String and it is assured that the queue() method is never called twice with the same parameters.

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Comment: If your primary key was too long you would have gotten an error trying to create the table. I've seen 767 as maximum length for InnoDB and 1000 for MyISAM (though I haven't verified them) and your key length comes in under that. Is it possible that the file you're batch loading from has dups?

Comment: What collation is your table using?  That will determine the bytes needed per char...

Comment: "latin1_swedish_ci" I'm not really sure what that means or why it is "swedish", to be honest. I added something I found about "rewriteBatchedStatements=true".

Comment: Could you show the exact Java code you used while "batch-inserting data" ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to answer my own question, but after hours of questioning my sanity, I finally found the problem. It has nothing to do with the length of the key, this is fine.
The Exception message just seems to get truncated at some point. The real issue was that the small **i** in latin1_swedish_ci means that keys are case-insensitive! And my data did, in fact, contain two URIs which only differed in capitalization.
Adding

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

to the table create statement solved the problem.

Thank you for your comments. I can not really comprehend why this behavior is the default, though.